# Collect directory updates into one email

Tags: python, email, directory, updates

I currently have a python script that notifies me of changes to a directory via email. However, because I am notified of updates to OneNote documents (which autosave once a change is made) I am sent multiple emails when a document is edited.

I want all updates that happen in a 10 minute period to be sent to me in one email, but I don't know how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
    import os
import win32file
import win32con
import win32com.client

o   = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")


ACTIONS = {
  1 : "Created",
  2 : "Deleted",
  3 : "Updated",
  4 : "Renamed from something",
  5 : "Renamed to something"
}

FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001

path_to_watch =r"\\FILE-LUX12-03\lux12_Translation\Translation\jllevent\QA_threads"
hDir = win32file.CreateFile (
  path_to_watch,
  FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
  win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
  None,
  win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
  win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
  None
)
while 1:

  results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
    hDir,
    1024,
    True,
    win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
     win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
     win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
     win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
     win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
     win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
    None,
    None
  )
  for action, file in results:
      if file.endswith(".one"):
          if action in (1, 2, 3):
              full_filename = os.path.join (path_to_watch, file)
              Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
              Msg.To = "emailaddress"
              Msg.Subject = "NOTIFICATION OF UPDATE"
              newbodyvariable = str(full_filename) + " has been " + str(ACTIONS.get (action, "Unknown"))
              Msg.Body = newbodyvariable
              Msg.Send()
```

Comment: Just put in an `if` condition to check if there is a 10 min gap between now and last sent email (maybe before `o.createItem` line). If over 10 min, then send.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just check every 10 minutes and then send aggregated data via email?

```
import time
while 1:
      time.sleep(60 * 10)
      results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
        hDir,
        1024,
        True,
        win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
        None,
        None
      )
      all_changes = []
      for action, file in results:
          if file.endswith(".one"):
              if action in (1, 2, 3):
                  full_filename = os.path.join (path_to_watch, file)
                  all_changes.append((full_filename, ACTIONS.get (action, "Unknown")))
      if all_changes:
          Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
          Msg.To = "emailaddress"
          Msg.Subject = "NOTIFICATION OF UPDATE"
          newbodyvariable = "; ".join("{full_filename} has been {action}".format(full_filename, action) for full_filename, action in all_changes)
          Msg.Body = newbodyvariable
          Msg.Send()
```